# Passing controller scope from directive to partial

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am new to AngularJs. I have a route configured to a controller and a template. In the template I am calling a custom directive. The custom directive loads a partial file in which I need to fetch the scope which is set by the controller. How can I pass the scope from the directive to the partial so that the partial file can consume the scope data.

Kindly let me know how to get this implemented in AngularJs

Code snippet inside the link function of the directive:

```
myApp.directive('basicSummary', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace:'true',
    templateUrl: "partials/basicSummary.html",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      console.log(scope.testURL);
    }
  }
});
```

Output on the console is : undefined

Update: I found the root cause of why the variable was not getting initialized. The issue, is that the variable is being fetched by making an ajax call in the controller and by the time the ajax call is completed and the variable is put inside the scope inside the controller, the partial file is already loaded and hence I am getting the value of the variable inside the directive as `undefined`.

How can I make sure that only on success of the `http` call, I load the partial and the directive?

Adding the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/prashdeep/VKkGz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a new variable to your scope in the definition of your directive to create a two-way binding, that you could safely watch for changes (for use in Javascript once the variable has been populated via ajax), and in your template use ng-show to show/hide based on whether or not the variable is defined. See this JSFiddle for an example of how that would work: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3588/

**Default Template**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <my-test my-test-url="myAjaxProperty"></my-test>
</div>
```

**App Definition**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('myTest', function(){
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        repalce: 'true',
        template: '<div ng-show="myTestUrl">{{myTestUrl}}</div>',
          scope: { myTestUrl: '=' },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){

          scope.$watch('myTestUrl', function(newVal, oldVal){
            if(newVal){
              console.log("Watched value is defined as: "+scope.myTestUrl);
            }
          })
        }
      }
    });

function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) {

    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.myAjaxProperty = "My Test Url";
        console.log("Ajax returned");
    }, 3000, true)


     console.log("Default Controller Initialized");
}
```

Comment: And till the partial is loaded with data, how can I show a spinner till the variable gets initialized from the ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

as long as you don't isolate your scope with,

```
scope: {}
```

in your directive, your scope has access to its parent controller's scope directly.

Comment: But how can I access the scope variable inside a script? I understand that i can access the scope variable in html using `{{}}` but what if I want to use a scope variable inside a javascript function? How can I  get the reference inside the directive's link function?

Comment: scope.variable or $scope.variable, however you pass it.  I think scope is the norm now.

Comment: I am trying to access the scope.variable inside the link function but I am getting undefined. I have updated my question with the code snippet

Comment: Pradeep, at what point are you setting this scope variable to a value? I just built a sample that mimics this, and it logs to the console fine.

Comment: can you tell me where you defined scope.testURL?

Comment: Inside the controller which is configured in the routes @z.a.

Comment: Could you please share the jsfiddle link if possible. I am struck on this issue since two days. Reply to @AndrewChurch

Comment: I am able t get the scope value inside the html but I want it to be used in a javascript function. I am not getting the value in the javascript.

Comment: and your directive is in the ng-view?

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you please let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: you can add routing and then use resolve: option to make sure data is ready before the page renders.